# How to use a Python 2 module and a Python 3 module together?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, python-requests, python-module

I want to be able to make calls to both [this Python 2 API](https://github.com/bitsoex/bitso-py) and [this Python 3 API](https://github.com/veox/python3-krakenex) from the same code.

There is a Python 2 version of the latter API but its surface is too small. No Python 3 version of the former.

I found [this document](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/cporting.html#cporting-howto) that seems to suggest the only way to make them compatible is by manually making several changes to the code, which, since I learned python a couple of days ago, is likely to lead to a host of errors and problems.

Other ideas to access both APIs together also welcome.

Much appreciated.

Comment: If you're new to Python, i recommend you learning and using Python3. Python2 is a legacy and its support will end soon. There will be only Python3 in the next years. Howver you can port your python2 code to python3 ([link](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html)).

Comment: I just skimmed the contents of the first one, but it doesn't look all that difficult to port to python3, other then replacing `print` statements and the "shebang" of the files, I didn't see anything particular different in syntax. If you do have errors after the switch, research it, or open a new question about it.

Comment: Thank you. I'm probably worrying unnecessarily before the fact. I'll just try porting the old module(s).

Answer (score 1):

That bitso-py library is just a Python wrapper for a REST API. If the library is not compatible with Python 3, you can make the relevant REST calls directly using something like the `requests` library.

Comment: Thank you. I'm new to coding. The other API's website says "The Kraken team has provided a basic PHP library for interfacing with the Kraken REST API." and "Use this library class to make calls to the Kraken REST API with a PHP client." (https://www.kraken.com/help/api) Does that mean I can just use the requests library you mention to make calls to both from Python? Why is there talk of PHP? Does it mean I need to use PHP directly instead of Python? Apologies for the generalized confusion.

Comment: Well I was looking at the Bitso one, which is [fully documented](https://bitso.com/api_info/#error-codes). Ignore any talk of PHP, you just make the calls directly to their HTTP endpoints. `requests` is an easy-to-use HTTP library.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try what you're saying and or porting the code to make it compatible as suggested above. Is there a way for me to put this question on hold or deleting it in a way such that I can re-instate it later without writing a new question if needed?